# Angular controller scope inheritance vs service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

On my site I have a navbar component that I want to customize for each and every ng-view I end up loading. Currently I'm doing this as follows. I have a NavCtrl for the navbar itself and my ng-view directive sits outside the scope of this controller. And I use a navbar service to change/override functionality in the navbar e.g each of my views need to override the click handler for a save button my navbar. The NavbarService has hookes to set the save function. And in the NavCtrl the $scope.save = NavbarService.save

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/world', {templateUrl : 'world.html', controller : 'WorldCtrl'}).otherwise({templateUrl : 'hello.html', controller : 'HelloCtrl'});
});

app.service('NavbarService', function() {
  var message = 'Save button not clicked yet',
      saveFunction = function() {
    this.setMessage('Default save called');
  };
  
  this.save = function() {
    _saveFunction();
  };
  
  this.setSaveFunction = function(funct) {
    _saveFunction = funct;
  };
  
  this.setMessage = function(newMessage) {
    message = newMessage;
  };
  
  this.getMessage = function() {
    return message;
  }
});

app.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $location, NavbarService) {
  $scope.message = NavbarService.getMessage();
  $scope.save = NavbarService.save;
  $scope.world = function() {
    $location.path('/world');
  };
  
  $scope.hello = function() {
    $location.path('/hello');
  };
  
  $scope.$watch(NavbarService.getMessage, function(newValue) {
    $scope.message = newValue;
  });
});

app.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope, NavbarService) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    NavbarService.setSaveFunction(function() {
      NavbarService.setMessage('Save method called from the HelloCtrl');
    });
  };
});

app.controller('WorldCtrl', function($scope, NavbarService) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    NavbarService.setSaveFunction(function() {
      NavbarService.setMessage('Save method called from the WorldCtrl');
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>My App</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <nav ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    <button ng-click="world()">Go to world</button>
    <button ng-click="hello()">Go to hello</button>
    <pre>{{message}}</pre>
  </nav>

  <div ng-view onload="init()"></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="hello.html">
    <h2>Active view is Hello</h2>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="world.html">
    <h2>Active view is World</h2>
  </script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-resource.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm wondering if I'm making this too complicated. I think the same thing can be achieved by just nesting the ng-view directive within the NavCtrl's scope. That way I can override $scope.save in each view controller.

But most the documentation states that services are the preferred way to share resources across controllers. Is one way better than the other? Why?

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: You have a couple anti patterns going on here. You should never modify the DOM from a controller/service. They're intended only to manage data/state. #message should either be part of the template, and be changed by the template change, or have its own controller that listens to the route and modifies a scope property that drives the message.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I merely needed to demonstrate the "Save" button executes the save method on the active view controller. #message is there just to display a log. In other other words, quick and dirty. I have modified my code snippet to eliminate the irregularities you pointed out.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to codereview site, as it provides a full working code and asks for reviewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I will have to repeat the `<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>` element in every template if since all my views need that button.

This comment clears up a few things, and in that case I do not necessarily recommend the [dynamic/declarative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424938/1121919) approach.  Instead, this particular UX can be considered more of a *static* UX and I'd do something a little differently that **still** avoids any *service* or *scope inheritance*.   I suggest using the following:

## app level

Your app level nav can still borrow the other answer's suggestion, however let's disregard the dynamic/declarative content.  So the nav looks like:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-submenu2">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-submenu2">

        <!-- container for dynamic view-specific menu content -->
        <li nx-view-menu-container class="nav navbar-nav">
        </li>

        <!-- static nav items -->
        <li class="nav navbar-nav">
            <a ng-click="saveRqst()">
                <span class="current-del-name">Save</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

The app-level controller would have this:

```
.controller 'appController', [
    '$scope'
    ($scope)->
         $scope.saveRqst = ->
             $scope.$root.$broadcast 'saveRqst', <addt. data if applicable>
]
```

## per view level controller

This makes a few assumptions:

- only on of these types of views are ever present (meaning it's one view/controller per application state, otherwise you might have 2 controllers trying to process a save rqst)
- your views reside as a child within your application template
- your views adhere to the normal view controller paradigm (meaning they're not special directives with isolate scopes)

  .controller 'someController', [
       '$scope'
       ($scope)->
           $scope.$on 'saveRqst`, (data)-> #do something for this view
  ]

Now I know this looks kinda like the scope inheritance bit, but it's not.  You have to define your save logic per view controller logic anyway, there's no getting around that if I've understood what you've presented in the question and other answer's comment.  The one nice bit about this *event bus* approach is it's easy enough to track the logic.  If you notate your code, then another developer who's had any experience working with Java or Flex or whatever, will easily be able to get up to speed on implementing additional views w. save logic.

So I've presented 2 approaches to this.  One is the [more dynamic, declarative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424938/1121919) and this one is the more static, yet unique-per-view approach.

Answer (score 0):

## preface & some history

Let me propose something that *utilizes neither a service, nor scope inheritance*.  Here is a similar issue I was trying to tackle.  I have views that get loaded via *ui.router's* `ui-view` (we're basically talking application states here right?).  I have my normal application nav & subnav, something like this...

```
['findings', 'tasks', 'reports', 'blah']
```

...that are common to all views.  But I also have some specific UI per view that I want wired to that view's $scope/controller.  In other words, I may have a dropdown specific to the current view, and a typeahead for another view.  I elected to tackle this declaratively with a directive rather than trying to force some inheritance override paradigm.

## directives

#### nxViewMenuContainer

First off I made a directive that was simply a container for housing the declared elements specific the views' nav elements.

```
.directive 'nxViewMenuContainer', [
    ()->
        dir =
            restrict: 'EAC'
            link: ($scope, elem, attrs)->
                if !elem.attr 'id'
                    elem.attr 'id', 'nx-view-menu-container'

                $scope.$root.$on '$stateChangeSuccess', ->
                    elem.empty()
]
```

This is implemented like so:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-submenu2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-submenu2">

            <!-- container for dynamic view-specific menu content -->
            <li nx-view-menu-container class="nav navbar-nav">
            </li>

            <!-- static nav items -->
            <li class="nav navbar-nav" ng-repeat="nav in app.subnav">
                <a><span class="current-del-name">{{nav.label}}</span></a>
            </li>
```

#### nxViewMenu

This directive is declared on each view and serves as the view-specific elements container that gets moved to the directive above.

```
.directive 'nxViewMenu', [
    ()->
        dir =
            restrict: 'EAC'
            link: ($scope, elem, attrs)->

                elem.ready ->
                    name = attrs.nxViewMenu or '#nx-view-menu-container'
                    target = $(name)

                    if !target.length
                        return

                    target.empty()
                    target.append elem

]
```

And inside each view where I might want a dynamic menu to appear in else where (in this case, in the app-level's nav container) I declare it inside my view templates.

**view 1**

```
<div class="nx-view-menu">
    <a class="btn btn-default">
        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-bars nx-clickout-filter"></i>
        <!--<label name="panel-title" style="color:#58585b; padding-left:5px;" class="nx-clickout-filter">Quick Links</label>-->
    </a>
</div>
```

**view 2**

```
<div class="nx-view-menu">
    <input typeahead="...">
</div>
```

**view 3**

```
<div class="nx-view-menu">
    <date-picker>...</date-picker>
</div>
```

## closing arguments

- Firstly you are doing things declaratively so it's easy to follow the logic once you understand the directives.
- It keeps the top level controllers ignorant of the specific views' logic while still displaying the DOM in a consistent way
- It bypasses the need for special services or some hacky message bus
- It simplifies your overall DOM structure because you don't need to set up some dual-view containers (in my case that was the other option in using *ui.router*) or parallel states.

Comment: I'll try to set up a demo when I can

Comment: Hey @jusopi thanks for the suggestion. Your solution will work for my situation. However I will have to repeat the `<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>` element in every template if since all my views need that button. And this is just one of the elements that all views are using. I can always encapsulate that html in another template and include it in all my views. But I dunno if I like the idea of essentially deleting and and re-adding the dom elements. I imagine if two views have the same element on the `navbar` then during the locationChange we will see a slight flicker.

Comment: Will setup a plnkr tonight and verify it this really is an issue. I like the idea that your approach will be more descriptive in terms of failure. I will know exactly where I haven't implemented the `$scope.save` method.

Comment: For elements that are always present, just the logic differs (meaning the current view controller implements the function) then have your top level app use `$scope.$root.$broadcast('save')` and each view's controller use `$scope.$on('save', ...)`.  This assumes that you only have one current view (sounds like you do).  Also be sure to cleanup your listeners via `$scope.$on('$destroy, cleanupFunc)`.

Comment: Regarding your comment about flickering when adding/removing DOM elements, I have yet to experience this.